# JAXB: Namespace annotation not inherited during unmarshalling - regression in JDK 1.8_102?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-namespaces, unmarshalling

I ran into a situation where JAXB refuses to unmarshal an XML element unless the corresponding Java field has a namespace annotation. This behavior only started in JDK 1.8.0_111 (or possibly in 102). Earlier versions of JDK 1.8 work.

**Test case:**

Java class (shortened):

```
package my.package;
@XmlRootElement(name = "MyElement", namespace="myns")
public class MyElement {
    @XmlElement(name = "subEl")
    private String subEl;
}
```

XML:

```
<MyElement xmlns="myns">
    <subEl>text1</subEl>
</MyElement>
```

package-info.java:

```
@XmlSchema(elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package my.package;
```

Unmarshalling code:

```
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyElement.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    MyElement myel = (MyElement) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStream);
    System.out.println("Parse result: "+ myel);
```

With JDK 1.8.0_101 (and earlier) this prints:

> Parse result: MyElement [subEl=subEl]

With JDK 1.8.0_111 I get:

> Parse result: MyElement [subEl=null]

So JDK 1.8.0_111 refuses to unmarshal the element "MyElement".

If I specify the namespace on the field annotation:

```
    @XmlElement(name = "subEl", namespace="myns")
    private String subEl;
```

it works as expected in all JDK versions.

---

What is going on here?

As far as I understand, the setting `elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED` should cause all fields of class MyElement to "inherit" the namespace of the class. The [Javadocs for `@XmlElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html#namespace--) say:

> If the value is "##default", then the namespace is determined as
>   follows:
>
> If the enclosing package has XmlSchema annotation, and its
>   elementFormDefault is QUALIFIED, then the namespace of the enclosing
>   class. Otherwise '' (which produces unqualified element in the default
>   namespace.
>
> Default: "##default"

**So why does JDK 1.8.0_111 not unmarshal the element?**

Note: JAXB bug report [#1087 - Unmarshalling Wrapped elements with elementForName=qualified fails](https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/issues/1087) (formerly at [JAXB-1087- Unmarshalling Wrapped elements with elementForName=qualified fails](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-1087)) seems to report the same problem - no response so far.

Comment: This JDK bug looks related (though not the same): [JDK-8134111 : Unmarshaller unmarshalls XML element which doesn't have the expected namespace](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8134111).

Comment: Similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41608667/axis-jaxb-unmarshal-not-working-with-any-jdk-except-jdk-1-8-077

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the relevant bug - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8165299

From which I can say that there was indeed a *fix* for JAXB.
So this strange behavior which ends up in null values is a wrong JAXB mapping and not a regression in Java.

Comment: Good find. However, that bug was closed as "Not an issue". So no fix.

Comment: I think you should fix your JAXB mapping.