# AXIS-JAXB Unmarshal not working with any JDK except jdk 1.8.077

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jaxb, wsdl

I have followed the below procedures:

1. Generated client files in eclipse using WSDL (Apache Axis 1).
2. Using JAXB to unmarshal the request XML and then call the webservice.

If I use JDK 1.8.077 then the XML is getting parsed successfully. If I use any other JDK like version 1.8.102 or 1.8.112 JAXB is unable to parse properly and returns a `null` value for the element.

Could anyone please suggest me the issue here?

Comment: As pointed out by  @Andrei Urvantcev , this looks a lot like the problem described in the question [JAXB: Namespace annotation not inherited during unmarshalling - regression in JDK 1.8_102?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40889384/jaxb-namespace-annotation-not-inherited-during-unmarshalling-regression-in-jd).

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the same faulty behavior with 1.8.111, after downgrading to 1.8.74 JAXB was able to parse properly.

Version 1.8.111:

```
JAXBContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new StreamSource(...), MyType.class).getValue()
```

returns a null

Comment: Could you please let me know the exact issue, which can be used to resolve.

Comment: Here is another one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40889384/jaxb-namespace-annotation-not-inherited-during-unmarshalling-regression-in-jd#

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reason for the issue is with the parser expecting the code to provide support for XML namespace with later versions of JDK 1.8.

In case you are using the SAX based parser to parse the XML document, make sure you set the namespaceAware API to true

final SAXParserFactory sax = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
sax.setNamespaceAware(true);

By default the value is set as **false**

I faced the same issue using the JDK version **1.8.121** & **1.8.131** with the SAX based parser and the issue got resolved by simply setting the value true for namespaceAware API for SAXParserFactory instance.

NOTE: The JAXB classes were generated from eclipse